# Google Play Store App Searching Issue

Tags: android, google-play, google-search

I have published my first application on google play and as usual its new experience so there are new "problems". When i search my application with exact name (sms planner), it does not list my app in search result but if i write smsplanner then i can see my app in 4th position.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=project.planner.sms
```

i guess the reason is project name space, as you can see project.planner.sms

How can i add some kind of "tags" so google can list my app with atleast exact name search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Comment: nice.. but this is related to android development. thanks for negative marking

Comment: This is weird. but your namespace is terrible. It should be com.yourwebsite.smsplanner, the namespace is just there to provide a unique identifier to your app. Bumping search results is linking to your app from your website, make sure to include search words in your description and make it compatible with a lot of devices. Check your developer console for compatability or if you get any error messages. Edit: meh, not really off topic

Comment: off topic - and finding your app on top is not controlled by just name. There are so many apps of similar names or matching names in the store. App to come in the top search is dependent on so many other factors like you app download, rating, like and all. As a user I expect the app which are famous and used by so many people should come in the top rather than name match.

Comment: @Pontus, i think you are righ, it may be bacause name space issue. but before pushing to the market google verify it if name space is valid or not. but if you could explain more what is developer console stuff

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/  where you uploaded your app etc. Go through the details of your release and check if there are any errors or warnings.. The namespace should not have an impact on the search but I'm not sure

Comment: @Shaleen your points are valid and there are all in my mind, but my or your app would never famous if it would not appear in the list not even in exact search result. let say if i do not have friends and my app is worth downloading then? what if it would not appear in list even on the bottom... just food for thought..

Comment: @Shaleen you should check play store before saying anything, his app doesn't show up at all when searching on the exact name of it

Answer (score 0):

Alright I looked at appbrain.com and this is the steps I think you should take:

- Set a min version and target version in your manifest (this could be the problem, if it's not declared, which seems weird)
- Upload a feature graphic

Comment: ah I see that it says theres no min or target version on my app as well, so this is probably just a problem with apptimizer

Comment: i have mentioned min and max version, its not a problem , i wonder how android would allow to compile without it (i did not check it)

Comment: It shouldn't be able to upload it, but as I said, check developer console for any errors, search through every page. I find it very weird that it doesn't show up at all, there's not a lot of apps with around the same name